# HTML & CSS -Div

Tags: html, css

Hi I've just started learning HTML & CSS and I'm doing some exercises, I'm wondering how can I remove the blank space between the 2 pictures (that thin white line)

Here's a picture for reference[image]

Here's the code

`````
    <div class="content">
      <h1>Plan Your Visit</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit.  Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit consectetur adipiscing elit, sed. </p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit.  Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit consectetur adipiscing elit, sed.</p>
      <button class="btns">More</button>
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="photo2.jpeg">
    </div>
    
   
    <div class="content">
      <h1>Plan Your Visit</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit.  Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit consectetur adipiscing elit, sed. </p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit.  Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit consectetur adipiscing elit, sed.</p>
      <button class="btns">More</button>
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="photo2.jpeg">
    </div>````
CSS

body{
  background-color: white;
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
}
.content{

  color: black;
  margin-top: 100px;
  margin-left: 30px;
  padding-right: 200px;
  text-align: justify;
}
h1{
  font-size: 50px;
}
p{
  margin-top: 10px;
  float:left
}
main{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}
img{
  max-width: 100%;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-left: auto;
  width: auto;
}````
`````

Comment: try removing "margin-top:100px" from content tag inside CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It probably has to do with the height of your image.
Try adding:

```
  height: 100%;
```

to the img css